# Однотипные маршруты в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

В моем приложении появляется слишком много однотипных маршрутов. Разницы между ними практически нет, кроме названия контроллера и самого метода.

Например `products/view_characteristics`, `products/view_attributes`, `products/view_info`, `products/view_photos` и так далее.

Все они обрабатываются одним контроллером `ProductsController`.

Как мне сделать что-то на подобии такого маршрута

```
Route::post('{controller}/{action}', function(){
    // здесь вызываем переданный метод у переданного контроллера 
});
```

Есть ли в самом фреймворке такая возможность(как вариант сторонние библиотеки) или придется пилить собственные велосипеды и костыли?

Comment: `Route::post('{controller}/{action}', function($controller, $action){});` кто вам мешает так обрабатывать?

Comment: Можно делать типа `Route::post('{controller}/{action}', function($controller, $action){ app()->call([$controller::class, $action]);});` если я не ошибаюсь и правильно понимаю документацию

Comment: @Walfter спасибо вам за совет. Он мне подошел по всем параметрам.

Answer (score 3):

> появляется слишком много однотипных маршрутов

Вы столкнётесь с проблемой, при выполнении кэширования маршрутов `php artisan route:cache`:

```
Unable to prepare route ... for serialization. Uses Closure.
```

Маршруты с анонимными функциями не кэшируются.

Предположу, что метод должен быть всё таки `get`:

```
// Ресурсный маршрут должен идти перед маршрутом из вопроса.
// Чтобы не было пересечений с маршрутом `products/{id}/edit`.
Route::resource('products', 'ProductsController');

// Маршрут из вопроса.
Route::get('products/{id}/{action}', 'ProductsController@detail');
```

Примерная обработка метода `detail` в контроллере `ProductsController`:

```
public function detail(int $id, string $action)
{
  // Делаете выборку товара по $id.
  ...

  // Возвращаете один из методов контроллера.
  // Предварительно проверив его существование.
  return $this->{camel_case($action)}();
}
```

Comment: Ваш вариант хорош, но я абсолютно не хотел выносить логику маршрутизации в контроллер. Я считаю что контроллер должен заниматься обработкой запроса а не строить маршруты.

Comment: @Arendach, да какая там логика? Типичный ларавеловский метод `show` с дополнительным параметром. Его вообще можно отлавливать через `request`. Я думаю, когда вы вплотную начнете использовать Laravel, то надобность в подобных костылях отпадет. А почему метод `post`?

Comment: Я наведу простой пример, у меня есть на странице действие я жму кнопку и мне нужно подгрузить форму какую-нибудь. таких форм может быть несколько с одним-двумя отличиями и чтобы не писать для каждого действия маршрут я и задался таким вопросом. Сейчас я пишу админку и красивых маршрутов мне не надо. Надо практических, то есть `/module/controller/action` вот такого вида.

Answer (score 0):

Свою проблему я решил следующим методом.

Написал функцию которая будет обрабатывать логику и вызывать нужный метод у переданного контроллера. Также в параметрах функции есть возможность указать пространство имен(если контроллер находится подкаталоге) а также для вызываемого метода префикс(это суто под себя сделал).

```
if (!function_exists('simple_routing')) {
    function simple_routing($controller, $action, $namespace_part, $action_prefix = '')
    {
        $namespace = '\\App\\Http\\Controllers\\' . $namespace_part . '\\' . \Illuminate\Support\Str::camel($controller) . 'Controller';

        $object = new $namespace;

        if (!method_exists($object, $action_prefix . $action)) {
            abort(404, __('common.errors.post_404'));
        }

        return app()->call([new $namespace, $action_prefix . $action]);
    }
}
```

Маршрут я прописывал следующим образом

```
Route::post('blog/{controller}/{action}', function ($controller, $action) {
    return simple_routing($controller, $action, 'Blog', 'action_');
});
```

По своей сути пространство имен являет собой разбиение приложения на модули. Но это так к слову.

Спасибо @Walfter за то что подтолкнул в правильном направлении.